# Change the stacking order for desktop and tablet/mobile (top to bottom, bottom to top)

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

Is there any possible way to change the layout from top to bottom and bottom to top on responsive design? Example as shown below:

**Desktop Layout**

- price on top
- hours and date on bottom

[image]

**CHANGE TO FOLLOWING LAYOUT ON TABLET/MOBILE (RESPONSIVE DESIGN)**

**Tablet/Mobile Layout**

- hours and date on top
- price on bottom

[image]

```css
.price{
  background-color: #ededed;
  width: 195px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 
 @media (max-width: 1023px){
    /* CHANGE LAYOUT */
 }
```

```html
<div class="price">$ 546.00</div>
26 hours<br/>
16 Oct 2007 - 27 Oct 2018
```

I don't have anything to show on code, insert to here so that easy to understand. If possible, I don't want `display:none` for desktop layout and create a new one for tablet/mobile.

Comment: You can use position absolute OR flexboxes and set a specific order. Do you know how to use these solutions?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/cj1k1uyc/

Comment: Or this? `flex-direction: column-reverse;`